# Where do I find the source code (.rs files) mentioned in The Rust Programming Language book?

Tags: rust

The Rust Programming Language book (ISBN 
9781593278281) has a link on page xxvii to download the source code for the files used in the book here: https://www.nostarch.com/rust

The link is no longer there so I assume that link has been removed since the Rust book is still a work in progress.  I did find the source code for actually making the book itself on GitHub, but not the .rs files used as examples in the book.

Was I misunderstanding that the link mentioned in the book was only for building the most recent copy of the Rust book itself OR was there an actual repository of the .rs files that were used in the examples from the book.

I have searched over GitHub but have not found an actual repo of .rs files used as examples in the Rust book. If one does exist, please post a link to it. (I have however stumbled across a lot of other good info I have saved such as rustlings).

Comment: I would recommend you to ask this question in the [rust user forum](https://users.rust-lang.org) because I know that the authors of the book check the forum very regularly.

Comment: The source code for the book content seems to be here: https://github.com/rust-lang/book but I don't see code samples

Comment: seems like others have the same request: https://github.com/rust-lang/book/issues/1889

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to get the source code files:
https://github.com/rust-lang/book/tree/extract-files

Download the ZIP file by clicking "Clone or Download" button.
Once the ZIP file is extracted the source code is here:
/book-extract-files/book-extract-files/listings

Thanks to Ultrasaurus for giving me the initial link several months ago to find this.

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting this link but as you can see in the [help/on-topic], asking for external resource is off-topic so your question is probably going to be closed as such. I'm not entirely sure where on the network such a question would belong, sadly =/